# MongoDB for a specific id, query returns array even though size is 0

Tags: mongodb

My collection structure is like this

```
{id:123, name:One, photos:[{id:"Test1",name:"Image One"},{"id":Test2,name:"Image Two"}]}
{id:124, name:One, photos:[]}
```

My main objective is to get the first element of the array based on the the `id` or `name` only if the size of the array is greater than 0.

But the said query returns the object even when the photos array is empty :

```
collection.find({"id":"124"},{"photos":{"$slice":[0,1]}})
```

I have also tried the where clause but still the result is the same

```
collection.find({"name":"album test"},{"photos":{"$slice":[0,1]},"$where":"photos.length > 0"})
```

Is there any better way of checking or querying for the objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
db.collection.find({id:124, "photos.0" : {$exists:true}},{"photos":{"$slice":[0,1]}})
```

Comment: Thanks Works great, I keep forgetting that that first part is the query and the second part is the columns or items to get..